# One to one relationship select query fetches data once first time only

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to apply one to one relationship between two entities 
first entity:
**Video** and **OrganzationVideo** every **OrganizationVideo** has one video entity

So I did the following

first **organization_video** table

```
CREATE TABLE  `organization_video` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**video** table

```
CREATE TABLE  `video` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
// rest of table contents
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

then I added constraint in **organization_video** table

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_organization_video` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `video` (`id`)
```

Then generated entities

**Video.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "video")
    public class Video extends Persistable<Long> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "video")
        private OrganizationVideo organizationVideo;
\\ rest of video contetns
    }
```

**OrganizationVideo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization_video")
public class OrganizationVideo extends Persistable<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Video video;
\\ rest of organziation video contents
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Default_Persistence_Unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/defaultDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="0"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

everything worked perfectly when persisting objects
the issue is with the fetching query

```
StringBuilder queryStr = new StringBuilder("select v from Video v where v.organizationVideo is null");
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryStr.toString());
return query.getResultList();
```

The weird behavior is that this query fetches data once then doesn't fetch any data tried to use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and changed `id` generation type with no luck but indeed there is something wrong it's strange to see data once first time when I tried to remove `is null` from query it fetches data but with null value assigned to `OrganizationVideo` then why the query doesn't work except at first time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the SQL that is generated for the query, but I'm guessing that since the ID is the foreign key and it is autogenerated, inserting entities causes problems with your query.  Try fixing your model first:

Either the OrganizationVideo  ID needs to be set by the video relationship (if using JPA 2.0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization_video")
public class OrganizationVideo extends Persistable<Long> {
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Video video;
\\ rest of organziation video contents
}
```

That, or you make one of the ID mappings within OrganizationVideo insertable=false, updatable=false.  if you do this, then you must set the other fields with in OrganizationVideo within the application yourself, and only after the Video instance has an ID value assigned.  Since you are using identity, this means you would have to persist the vidoe, flush, and then use that value within the OrganizationVideo before it can be persisted.

It would be easier for your model if you could just add a foreign key to the OrganizationVideo table and use that to reference the Video ID.

Comment: I've already tried ``@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "customForeignGenerator")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
            name = "customForeignGenerator",
            strategy = "foreign",
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "video")
    )`` in organizationVideo but same issue with loading query now I have no problem with persisting but the main issue is with select videos query

Comment: About your suggestion to add foreign key to OrganizationVideo that would generate one-to-many relationship and that is wrong since every entity has one copy only of other one

Comment: Find out the SQL from your query.  As for a foreign key- your case is trying to reuse the ID as the fk, which is exactly the same except it has a built in unique constraint.   The difference between a 1:M and 1:1 is just the constraint on the foreign key, which you can add yourself.